# Problems with seaborn (ndim)

Tags: python-3.x, plot, seaborn

I am using `seaborn` to plot a very simple data set. Here is what I do:

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('myfile.xlsx')

sns.set(style="white")

g = sns.PairGrid(df, diag_sharey=False)
g.map_lower(sns.kdeplot)
g.map_upper(sns.scatterplot)
g.map_diag(sns.kdeplot, lw=3)
```

I get the following error: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'ndim'`. Weirdly, the plot is ploted in parts (see below).

[image]

Any idea why that is the case and what I can do to solve the issue?

**EDIT:**

The dataframe has the following attributes:

```
plan_change          int64
user_login         float64
new_act_ratio      float64
on_time              int64
```

Unfortunately, I cannot upload the data set. However I can say, that plotting other seaborn graphs works just fine.

The total error message is the following:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-2dbc61abd2bd> in <module>()
      3 g = sns.PairGrid(df, diag_sharey=False)
      4 g.map_lower(sns.kdeplot)
----> 5 g.map_upper(sns.scatterplot)
      6 g.map_diag(sns.kdeplot, lw=3)
      7 

/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/seaborn/axisgrid.py in map_upper(self, func, **kwargs)
   1488                 color = self.palette[k] if kw_color is None else kw_color
   1489                 func(data_k[x_var], data_k[y_var], label=label_k,
-> 1490                      color=color, **kwargs)
   1491 
   1492             self._clean_axis(ax)

/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/seaborn/relational.py in scatterplot(x, y, hue, style, size, data, palette, hue_order, hue_norm, sizes, size_order, size_norm, markers, style_order, x_bins, y_bins, units, estimator, ci, n_boot, alpha, x_jitter, y_jitter, legend, ax, **kwargs)
   1333         x_bins=x_bins, y_bins=y_bins,
   1334         estimator=estimator, ci=ci, n_boot=n_boot,
-> 1335         alpha=alpha, x_jitter=x_jitter, y_jitter=y_jitter, legend=legend,
   1336     )
   1337 

/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/seaborn/relational.py in __init__(self, x, y, hue, size, style, data, palette, hue_order, hue_norm, sizes, size_order, size_norm, dashes, markers, style_order, x_bins, y_bins, units, estimator, ci, n_boot, alpha, x_jitter, y_jitter, legend)
    850 
    851         plot_data = self.establish_variables(
--> 852             x, y, hue, size, style, units, data
    853         )
    854 

/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/seaborn/relational.py in establish_variables(self, x, y, hue, size, style, units, data)
    155                 units=units
    156             )
--> 157             plot_data = pd.DataFrame(plot_data)
    158 
    159         # Option 3:

/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in __init__(self, data, index, columns, dtype, copy)
    264                                  dtype=dtype, copy=copy)
    265         elif isinstance(data, dict):
--> 266             mgr = self._init_dict(data, index, columns, dtype=dtype)
    267         elif isinstance(data, ma.MaskedArray):
    268             import numpy.ma.mrecords as mrecords

/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in _init_dict(self, data, index, columns, dtype)
    400             arrays = [data[k] for k in keys]
    401 
--> 402         return _arrays_to_mgr(arrays, data_names, index, columns, dtype=dtype)
    403 
    404     def _init_ndarray(self, values, index, columns, dtype=None, copy=False):

/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in _arrays_to_mgr(arrays, arr_names, index, columns, dtype)
   5382 
   5383     # don't force copy because getting jammed in an ndarray anyway
-> 5384     arrays = _homogenize(arrays, index, dtype)
   5385 
   5386     # from BlockManager perspective

/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in _homogenize(data, index, dtype)
   5693                 v = lib.fast_multiget(v, oindex.values, default=NA)
   5694             v = _sanitize_array(v, index, dtype=dtype, copy=False,
-> 5695                                 raise_cast_failure=False)
   5696 
   5697         homogenized.append(v)

/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py in _sanitize_array(data, index, dtype, copy, raise_cast_failure)
   2917 
   2918     # scalar like
-> 2919     if subarr.ndim == 0:
   2920         if isinstance(data, list):  # pragma: no cover
   2921             subarr = np.array(data, dtype=object)

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'ndim'
```

Comment: What's the content of `myfile.xlsx`? What's the errormessage (not just the last line)? See also [mcve].

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer! Unfortunately, I cannpt provide the dataset this time around. But I included the `dtypes` and the error message in the question (see section "Edit")